# Popup on hover with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm trying to apply [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-hover/), but since it's polygons and not points, and I'm not familiar with Javascript, I hope I could make the hover works with extruded polygons. I see that the hovering event  `style.cursor = 'pointer'` is working, but the popup is not appearing.

The text information is from a layer made in Mapbox studio. How do I correct the code to work with extruded polygons?

```
<body>
<style>
.mapboxgl-popup {
max-width: 400px;
font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
   mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia2V2aW5jYXJ2YWxobyIsImEiOiJjbDFsNDZnczgwNHVoM2lraGN0cWZlOHJvIn0./////';
   var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
       container: 'map',
       style: 'mapbox://styles/kevincarvalho/cldyij0bs000a01p6yosswikv',
   });

   // Create a popup, but don't add it to the map yet.
     var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
       offset: [0, 0],
       closeButton: false,
       closeOnClick: false
     });

 map.on('load', function() {
   map.on('mouseenter', 'edificios-perimetros-djws7r', function(e) {
     map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

     // Copy coordinates array.
     var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
     var title = e.features[0].properties.Legenda;

     // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
     // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
     // over the copy being pointed to.
     while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
     coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
     }

     // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
     // based on the feature found.
     popup
     .setLngLat(coordinates)
     .setHTML(title)
     .addTo(map);
     });

   map.on('mouseleave', 'edificios-perimetros-djws7r', function() {
     map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
     popup.remove();
   });
 });

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the `coordinates` var with the function `e.lngLat` and it's working now with 3D buildings:

```
  map.on('load', function() {
    map.on('mouseenter', 'edificios-perimetros-djws7r', function(e) {
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

      // Copy coordinates array.
      var title = e.features[0].properties.Legenda;

      // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
      // based on the feature found.
      popup
      .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
      .setHTML(title)
      .addTo(map);
      });

    map.on('mouseleave', 'edificios-perimetros-djws7r', function() {
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
      popup.remove();
    });
  });
```